# Trying to limit the max characters in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I'm trying to limit the max characters in a textarea, using JS, i leave here my HTML & JS code:

HTML-->

```
<form id="formu" action="ok.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        <label for="observaciones">Observaciones:</label>
        <textarea id="observaciones" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
    </p>
</form>
```

JS-->

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("observaciones").addEventListener('keypress',function(){maxlong(document.getElementById("observaciones")),150},false);
}

function maxlong(obj,maxlength){
        return(obj.value.length<=maxlength);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

your event handler doesn't actually do anything. You need to prevent the default beahviour of the event (with the preventDefault method on the event object).

Comment: I'm trying this now:

    function maxlong(elEvento){
 var evento=elEvento||window.event;
 var obser=document.getElementById("observaciones").value;

 if(obser.length >=5){
  evento.preventDefault();
 }
    }

with `document.getElementById("observaciones").addEventListener('keypress',maxlong,false);`

But still not working :(

Comment: That works fine for me. do you get any javascript errors? Make sure that the addEventListener call happens after the dom for the textarea is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by html :

```
<textarea maxlength="50"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  function limiter() {
    var area = document.getElementById("content_txt");
    var message = document.getElementById("message");
    var maxLength = 160;
    var checkLength = function () {
        if (area.value.length <= maxLength) {
            message.innerHTML = (maxLength - area.value.length) + " characters remainging";
        }
    }
    setInterval(checkLength, 300);
}
```

and this is the textarea

```
<textarea style="resize:none; margin-bottom: 0px;" id="content_txt" 
                    name="TextArea1" runat="server" 
                    maxlength="160" onkeyup="return limiter();" ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function maxLength(obj){

if(obj.value.length <=150){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}
</script>
<textarea onkeypress="return maxLength(this);"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is basic to set maxlength:**

```
<textarea maxlength="50">
Enter text here...
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved doing this:

```
function maxlong(elEvento){
    var evento=elEvento||window.event;
    var obser=document.getElementById("observaciones").value;

    if(obser.length>=15){
        evento.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

And also i had an extra "{" that made the program not working well...